# How to fix DSpace oai not showing special characters?

Tags: diacritics, dspace, oai

My DSpace install is working fine, the metadata is being stored and showed correctly in any browser. The database has been confirmed as UTF-8. The problem is that the oai protocol shows accents and diacritics in letters (áéíóúüUñÑ etc) as ? like **Dise?o** instead of **Diseño** and all the entities that harvest our metadata report this problem. If you would like to see for yourselves, this is the link: http://repositorio.puce.edu.ec/oai/request?verb=Identify

I can't find any file that sets the encoding for the oai protocol nor any kind of solution for this problem.

Comment: I am running DSpace 5.6 and my collection names are displaying properly in the OAI harvester.  Which version of DSpace are you running?  Once simple thing you could do is force a rebuild of the OAI index (and then clear the OAI cache).

Comment: @terrywb I'm using DSpace 4.1, I already executed those two commands to no avail.

Comment: This might point to a solution: https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-2343

Comment: does DSpace need to be recompiled after that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this thread: http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/OAI-tp4681419.html, you have to set `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in `JAVA_OPTS`. Then do a clean and force a rebuild of your OAI index as @terrywb mentioned (ie `bin/dspace oai clean-cache` and `bin/dspace oai import -c -o`.

Comment: Thank you, that was already configured in JAVA_OPTS but still the same results.

Comment: After a couple of weeks with this headache I finally solved the issue. You were kind of right about your answer so that's why I'll choose it as the accepted answer. In Ubuntu this works fine but in Red Hat Linux the value must be set as -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 instead of -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8. I rebooted the server after changing this and rebuilding the index showed the correct characters!

Answer (score 1):

When you run `bin/dspace oai import -c` make sure you are running it with UTF-8 locale. For example use LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8. It's mentioned in the documentation and also filed as an issue https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-2033

Comment: just did that but it still shows me the wrong characters. It's good to know someone else has experienced these issues

Answer (score 1):

Have yow set the URIencoding into tomcat's server.xml?

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Well, it was like that from the beginning, but could it be that I've configured Tomcat to work on port 80? I tried changing the port number in that file but tomcat refused to start after that change. It worked again when I changed it back to 8080. Should I add it as another connector?

Comment: dont worry about the port number,  URIEncoding="UTF-8" should be added to the http connector despite of the port

Comment: Thanks, I already set it in both connectors. I know I marked this question as answered but after a couple of days after it got fixed, the encoding failed again and I haven't been able to fix this